# How can I share hidden file to Whatsapp?

Tags: android, file, video, share, hidden

I have hidden video file :

> /data/user/0/com.android.android/files/.ModifiedVideo/MODIFIED_VIDEO20190927_162816324.mp4

I want to share this file to Whatsapp. But I take this error :

> "The file format is not supported"

How can I share hidden file?

```
private void shareVideo(){

 Intent chooserIntent;
 List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<>();
 List<ResolveInfo> intentActivities = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

 chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
 chooserIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(chooserIntent);

}
```